SDDM shows black screen and logs "Failed to read display number from pipe" (Arch ARM in QEMU)
I'm trying to set up Arch Linux ARM in a VM. I use UTM (a GUI frontend for QEMU) and I set up Arch using an ISO from archboot. I then installed SDDM, but when I run it with systemctl start sddm or the sddm command, it just shows a black screen. I added a serial console to my VM to look for any error messages, and sddm prints the following:
[15:27:24.053] (II) DAEMON: Initializing...
[15:27:24.062] (II) DAEMON: Starting...
[15:27:24.063] (II) DAEMON: Logind interface found
[15:27:24.065] (II) DAEMON: Adding new display...
[15:27:24.067] (II) DAEMON: Loaded empty theme configuration
[15:27:24.069] (II) DAEMON: Xauthority path: "/run/sddm/xauth_pWuPxs"
[15:27:24.070] (II) DAEMON: Using VT 2
[15:27:24.070] (II) DAEMON: Display server starting...
[15:27:24.071] (II) DAEMON: Writing cookie to "/run/sddm/xauth_pWuPxs"
[15:27:24.072] (II) DAEMON: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -background none -seat seat0
 vt2 -auth /run/sddm/xauth_pWuPxs -noreset -displayfd 15
[15:27:24.082] (EE) DAEMON: Failed to read display number from pipe
[15:27:24.083] (II) DAEMON: Display server stopping...
[15:27:24.084] (WW) DAEMON: Attempt 1 starting the Display server on vt 2 failed
[15:27:26.190] (II) DAEMON: Display server starting...
[15:27:26.195] (II) DAEMON: Writing cookie to "/run/sddm/xauth_pWuPxs"
[15:27:26.198] (II) DAEMON: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -background none -seat seat0
 vt2 -auth /run/sddm/xauth_pWuPxs -noreset -displayfd 15
[15:27:26.210] (EE) DAEMON: Failed to read display number from pipe
[15:27:26.213] (II) DAEMON: Display server stopping...
[15:27:26.216] (WW) DAEMON: Attempt 2 starting the Display server on vt 2 failed
[15:27:28.269] (II) DAEMON: Display server starting...
[15:27:28.272] (II) DAEMON: Writing cookie to "/run/sddm/xauth_pWuPxs"
[15:27:28.276] (II) DAEMON: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -background none -seat seat0
 vt2 -auth /run/sddm/xauth_pWuPxs -noreset -displayfd 15
[15:27:28.288] (EE) DAEMON: Failed to read display number from pipe
[15:27:28.291] (II) DAEMON: Display server stopping...
[15:27:28.293] (WW) DAEMON: Attempt 3 starting the Display server on vt 2 failed
[15:27:28.297] (EE) DAEMON: Could not start Display server on vt 2

As far as I understand, the actual error seems to occur in here:
[15:27:24.082] (EE) DAEMON: Failed to read display number from pipe

systemctl status sddm gives the same output.
I tried using different display types for my VM, but I only got worse results with them. The preconfigured display type which works flawlessly for the basic console is virtio-ramfb.
I don't have any X or SDDM configuration files on my system. Do I need them for SDDM to work?
And if you don't have any ideas to my problem, could you maybe explain me what this error message means? What "pipe" is X (I guess it's X) trying to read from, and what kind of "display number" does it expect?
Thank you
